# Skype call recording with real-time annotation / markers?

Tags: windows, software-rec, skype, recording, voip

There are plenty of applications to record Skype calls, but I am looking for one that allows you to place "chapter markers" or any sort of *bookmarks* or annotations at certain points in the call in real-time (i.e. while the call is in progress).

I found *this* program ([Call Recorder for Skype](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/callrecorder/)), but it is for Mac only.

Does anyone know of a **call recorder with real-time annotations for Windows?**

Answer (score 1):

Check out [G-Recorder](http://www.g-recorder.com). It doesn't provide exactly what you described. You can use chat messages for annotations, chat messages with timestamps are saved together with call recording in your mailbox.

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-author of G-Recorder*